# Is it possible to send templated emails via SES whilst in sandbox mode/

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am attempting to test the sending of a templated email via AWS SES via a python lambda function.

The process runs without any error and in the Cloudwatch log I do get a message stating that the email has been sent, however the email is not actually received (both the sending and receiving email addresses are verified).

If the same process is run without the template then the email is received.

Below is the code

```
`   template_data = {}
    template_data['toBeReplaced'] = body

    # print(json.dumps(template_data))
    strTemplateData = json.dumps(template_data)
    print(strTemplateData)

    response = client.send_templated_email(
      Source=SENDER,
      Destination={
        'ToAddresses': emailAdds,
        'CcAddresses': ['XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk']
      },
      ReturnPath='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xo.uk',
      Template='emailTemplate3',
      TemplateData=strTemplateData     
    )`
```

Comment: Can you share some code + template file? Are you sure that all template values are replaced?

Comment: @jogold I have added the code into the main post.  I am passing in a variable that makes up the test that is replacing the 'toBeReplaced' section in the template.  The replacement text is a string of HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the Rendering Failure CloudWatch metric ? If there is something is wrong with template (or the values you passed) , you still get 200OK and a Message ID but the email is actually rejected and can be shown in the Rendering Failure CloudWatch metric.

You can enable Configuration sets and enable SNS notification for rendering failure, you'll get an exact description on what went wrong in the template.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks for this. You were correct and it was the rendering of the template. i had made a mistake in the tag that was to be replaced. I have put {{toBeReplaced}}. I should have put `<div>{{toBeReplaced}}</div>` Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Will not forget this one in a hurry :-)